# How does the Arduberry work?

Tags: arduberry

I have an Arduberry for my RPi and wondered if it worked the same way as the Uno. I understand that it is **not** in fact an officially licensed Arduino but, I wanted to know if it worked the same way namely, in how it communicates as it connects to the GPIO header and does not use USB.

Also how similar is it to any other Arduinos?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Arduberry connects the Raspberry Pi with Arduino shields.  The Arduberry uses the GPIO headers on the Raspberry Pi to communicate with the Atmega 328 (it does not use USB).  It does have the same pinout as the Arduino Uno, and it uses the same chip.

The Arduberry is connected to the Raspberry Pi over Serial, I2C, and SPI.  Firmware is loaded to the Arduberry chip using the SPI lines.

Also as a bonus, the Arduberry works with the Raspberry Pi models B, B+ 2, 3, A, and Zero.

There is [extensive documentation for the Arduberry on the Dexter Industries website](http://www.dexterindustries.com/arduberry-tutorials-documentation/), as well as extensive examples, hardware design files, and information on [how to use the Arduberry on Github here](https://github.com/DexterInd/ArduBerry).

Comment: I f it dosn't use USB why does it have a USB port?

Comment: Originally added as an extra power option.  Say you wanted to add extra amperage for a high draw shield.

Comment: What about the other port?

Comment: Which other port?

Comment: On the board there is another port to the left of the USB, It looks like power.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell, because real documentation seems to be somewhat scant.

From what I can fathom it's an Arduino Uno which has had the USB interface removed and the TX/RX pins connected to the Pi's TX/RX pins instead (one would hope through a suitable level shifter).

What other pins on the GPIO might be connected (I2C, etc) I haven't been able to find out in the few moments I have been looking.

Comment: It is much less expensive to get an Arduino Nano and wire it to a Rpi rather than trying to make a FrankenPi...   Kinda cute, but who needs it?